# How to add another URL to the base URLs in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, url

Let's say I have two URLs in a list:

```
[
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=1", 
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=2" 
]
```

How can I turn the list above to this:

```
[
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=1&c=1", 
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=1&c=2",
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=1&c=3",
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=2&c=1", 
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=2&c=2", 
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=2&c=3", 
]
```

What is the syntactically cleanest way to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop over your existing URLs and the values you want to add:

```py
base = [
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=1", 
  "https://www.xxx.xxx/classroom/getTextNew.php?id=24&l=2" 
]
extended = [f'{url}&c={c}' for url in base for c in '123']
```